# setAdapter crashes the app

Tags: java, android, listview

I try to get Strings from firebase to a ListView but when i add the line

`listViewPerifereies.setAdapter(adapterPerifereies);`

the app crashes and it just stops. I am sure that the ListView is in the right .xml (activity_perifereies_list.xml). I have the same code in another activity and it works, but now it does not in any new activity i create.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PerifereiesList extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databasePaths;
private ListView listViewPerifereies;
private ArrayList<String> ArrayListPerifereies;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPerifereies;
Paths info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perifereies_list);

    listViewPerifereies = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.epitelous);
    ArrayListPerifereies = new ArrayList<>();

    databasePaths = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Paths");

    databasePaths.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayListPerifereies.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                info = items.getValue(Paths.class);
                ArrayListPerifereies.add(info.perifereia);
            }


            adapterPerifereies = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PerifereiesList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayListPerifereies);
            listViewPerifereies.setAdapter(adapterPerifereies);
            adapterPerifereies.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.spiros.mypath, PID: 7607
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409)
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2413)
                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1986)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:709)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:770)
                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1721)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2212)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1766)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1610)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1519)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1766)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1610)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1519)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:774)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2519)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2234)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6774)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7607 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please add the error you get if you get one.

Comment: I don't get any error. It is just stops when i open this activity when i run the app.

Comment: Nothing in the logcat? How do you know that `setAdapter` causes the crush?

Comment: Search the Logcat for any error messages related to your app. If the app stops running then there will be some kind of Exception with a stack trace. Please share this as well

Comment: My mistake. I post it now.

Comment: @MrUmbra The array in your ArrayAdapter contains at least one entry that is null. You should check your firebase database and if you are getting the items correctly. Try to Log them into the logcat.

Comment: @grrigore Omg you are right. When i first created and used  the firebase i did not created "perifereia", so it does not exists at first. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MrUmbra problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you've configured your adapter first
and then make sure you did the following : 
inside your onCreate();

```
      Adapter adapter = new Adapter (Context)
```

make sure you have passed the context only , then you can inflate your menu